# Matplotlib - smooth a line

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm looking for an advice on how to smoothen a trend line.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import random

#Generating the data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data = random.randn(5,4), index = ['A','B','C','D','E'],
columns = ['W','X','Y','Z'])

df['W'] = ['10/01/2018 12:00:00','10/03/2018 13:00:00',
           '10/03/2018 12:30:00','10/04/2018 12:05:00',
           '10/08/2018 12:00:15']

pd.to_datetime(df['W'])

print(df.head()) 

#Plotting hte graph
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x="W", y="X", ax=ax, color='salmon', alpha=0.5, marker='o')
df.plot(x="W", y="Y", ax=ax, color='royalblue', alpha=0.4, marker='o')
```

This is what I get:

[image]
[image]

I would like to get a smooth line,  something like this:
[image]

Comment: Matplotlib doesnt do any smoothing per se.  you should look at spline interpolation in numpy or pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `df.resample` method and `df.interpolate` to do what you desire.

First, `df.resample` computes the datetimes at which we will interpolate. After this we can go ahead and interpolate.

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Generating the data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data = random.randn(5,4), index = ['A','B','C','D','E'], 
                                          columns = ['W','X','Y','Z'])

df['W'] = pd.to_datetime(['10/01/2018 12:00:00','10/03/2018 13:00:00',
                           '10/03/2018 12:30:00','10/04/2018 12:05:00',
                           '10/08/2018 12:00:15'], infer_datetime_format=True)

#Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
df.plot(x="W", y="X", ax=ax, color='salmon', alpha=0.5, marker='o')
df.plot(x="W", y="Y", ax=ax, color='royalblue', alpha=0.4, marker='o')

df = df.resample('T', on='W').mean()

df.interpolate(method='spline', order=3, inplace=True)

df.plot(y='X', alpha=0.5, ax=ax, legend=False)
df.plot(y='Y',  alpha=0.4, ax=ax, legend=False)
```